# Setting Landscape orientation in phones using setRequestedOrientation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-orientation

When setting landscape orientation in an android apps activity using setRequestedOrientation the activity first comes up in portrait and then goes into landscape in phones. The setRequestedOrientaiton is called inside the onCreate lifecycle method. Is it possible to directly launch the activity in landscape orientation. Since we need the activity to be in landscape mode only on phones we are not able to set the orientation in manifest.xml file. (In tablets the activity should support any orientation)

Comment: You can define screenOrientation property in manifest file for each activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use the manifest to set orientation and get the value from ressources.

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="@integer/orientation" />
```

In your integers.xml files set the value as follow :

```
<integer name="orientation">0</integer> <!-- Force landscape mode -->

<integer name="orientation">1</integer> <!-- Force portrait mode -->

<integer name="orientation">2</integer> <!-- Use phone's orientation -->
```

Just create a integers.xml file for phones and another for tablets.

Comment: On adding am getting a warning saying :- Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) Found variation in sw600dp, sw720dp

I have added integers.xml in values, valjues-sw600dp,values-sw720dp

And the values are:
<integer name="orientation">0</integer> in values
<integer name="orientation">10</integer> in sw600dp and sw720dp.
ie 10 for full sensor orientation and landscape the other.

Comment: Also, I am able to run the app, but even in my Samsung galaxy tab S its coming up in the landscape, orientation-locked.

Comment: Also, this behaviour is not observed in Android 6, There on setting orientation to landscape in onCreate, the activity directly loads in landscape only. ie it doesn't go to portrait and comes back to landscape.